# Call SharedPreferences on IntentService

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, intentservice

I'm trying to set null a value on SharedPreferences on my `IntentService` but I'm getting `NPE`.
I Inject `SharedPreferences` from Dagger.

```
public class DenyService extends IntentService {

    @Inject
    NumberPreferences numberPreferences;

    public DenyService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public DenyService() {
        super("DenyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ((CustomApp) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        numberPreferences.setInt(Constants.CONTESTABLE_BOOKING_ID, null);
        ResultReceiver rec = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTag");
        rec.send(1, null);
    }
}
```

Is something wring with my code, or am I missing something about `onHandleIntent` method?

Comment: Which line causes the NPE?

Comment: `numberPreferences.setInt(Constants.CONTESTABLE_BOOKING_ID, null);`

Comment: So numberPreferencesis null. That means it wasn't injected. What is your model? Sorry if that isn't the right term. Dagger and IoC is very new top me.)